# Application Settings saving

Tags: c#, application-settings

I have two assemblies in my application. `MyApplication.BO` and `MyApplication.GUI`.

I have configured property-settings for my BO assembly.

Now when I am trying to compile the following code:

```
public class MyApplicationInfo
{
 private string _nameOfTheUser;
 public string FullNameOfTheUser
 {
  get { return _nameOfTheUser; }
  set { _nameOfTheUser = value; }
 } 

 public void Save()
 {
  try
  {
   MyApplication.BO.Properties.Settings.Default.FullNameOfTheUser = this.FullNameOfTheUser;

   MyApplication.BO.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
   throw ex;
  }
 }
}
```

VS2005 is giving me the following compilation error:

> Error 1 Property or indexer 'MyApplication.BO.Properties.Settings.FullNameOfTheUser' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only F:\CS\MyApplication\MyApplication.BO\MyApplicationInfo.cs 57 17 MyApplication.BO

What is wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In the Settings designer, make sure that the Scope property for FullNameOfTheUser is set to "User". If you create an Application-scoped setting, it is generated as a read-only property. Take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(VS.80).aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The setting needs to have user, not application scope.